# Как поменять значения индекса в Series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, index

У меня есть массив случайных величин:

```
s = pd.Series(data=np.random.normal(size=100))
```

Нужно создать массив их этих же данных, но с другой индексацией: возвести старую в квадрат.

Пыталась сделать так:

```
s1 = pd.Series(data=s,index=np.arange(0,99)**2)
```

Но массив теряет половину данных, так как сопоставляет данные нового массива со старой индексацией и проставляет `NaN` вместо данных.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что вы указываете индекс с меньшим числом элементов:

```
In [25]: len(np.arange(0,99))
Out[25]: 99

In [26]: len(s)
Out[26]: 100
```

попробуйте так:

```
s1 = pd.Series(data=s,index=np.arange(len(s))**2)
```

NOTE: это решение будет правильно работать только в том случае если в исходном ряду значения индекса: `[0, 1, 2, ...]`

---

но лучше сделать так:

```
s.index **= 2
```

или так:

```
s.index *= s.index
```

Результат:

```
In [18]: s
Out[18]:
0      -1.139308
1       0.150535
4      -0.644703
9      -0.021449
16     -1.995995
          ...
9025    0.539693
9216    2.191779
9409   -0.901023
9604   -0.131828
9801    1.730033
Length: 100, dtype: float64
```

Comment: "или `s.index *= s.index`" - для возведения в степень тоже есть сокращённая комбинация `s.index**=2`

Comment: @Евгений, wow! не знал об этом, спасибо! :)